# Using black with git clean filter

Tags: python, git

I'm trying to set up [black](https://github.com/ambv/black) to run on any files checked into git.

I've set it up as follows:

```
git config filter.black.clean 'black -'
echo '*.py filter=black' >> .git/info/attributes
```

As far as I understand, this should work ok as black with `-` as the source path will read from `STDIN` and output to `STDOUT`, which is what I think the git filter needs it to do.

However this does not work. When I add an un-black file with `git add` I see the following output:

```
reformatted -
All done! ✨  ✨
1 file reformatted.
```

And the file is not changed on disk. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Black documentation recommends using a pre-commit hook, rather than smudge and clean filters.  Note that `filter.black.clean` defines a *clean filter* and you have not set up any smudge filters.

The reason you see no change to the work-tree version of the file is that a clean filter is used when turning the work-tree version of a file into the index (to-be-committed) version of the file.  This has no effect on the work-tree version of the file!

A smudge filter is used in the opposite direction: Git has a file that is in the index—for whatever reason, such as because it was just copied into the index as part of the `git checkout` operation to switch to a specific commit—and desires to convert that in-the-index, compressed, Git-ized file to one that you can actually see and edit in your editor, or run with `python`.  Git will, at this time, run the (de-compressed) file contents through your smudge filter.

Note that if you convert some file contents, pre-compression, in a clean filter, and then later extract that file *from* the repository, into the index, and on into your work-tree, you will *at that time* be able to see what happened in the clean filter (assuming you do not have a countervailing smudge filter that undoes the effect).

In a code-reformatting world, one could conceivably use a *clean filter* to turn all source files into some sort of canonical (perhaps four-space-indentation) form, and a *smudge filter* to turn all source files into one's preferred format (two-space or eight-space indentation).  If these transformations are all fully reversible, what you would *see*, in your work-tree, would be in your preferred format, and what others would see in *their* work-trees would be their preferred format; but what the version control system itself would see would be the canonical, standardized format.

That's not how Black is actually intended to be used, though it probably can be used that way.

Comment: Thanks that was very helpful. My isue with the pre-commit hook is that I ended up with the unblackened files committed, and another set of local changes of the blackened files, so a single commit would essentially become two, unless the files were black to begin with. Maybe I configured it wrong though...

Comment: Another debug hint: Git will also do certain optimizations when it can, when it thinks files are already appropriately clean or smudged, so it's possible some cases don't go through the filter. Setting the environment variable `GIT_TRACE` to a nonzero value lets you observe some of the internal activity, including the running of filters.

Answer (score 2):

It's not obvious how to set this up manually, but [using the pre-commit framework](https://ljvmiranda921.github.io/notebook/2018/06/21/precommits-using-black-and-flake8/) seems to work well.

This approach does two things:

1. checks prior to committing that the files pass the `black` test
2. runs `black` to fix the files if they don't

So if files don't pass, the commit fails, and black fixes the files which you then need to `git -add` before trying to commit again.

In a separate test, I managed to set up the pre-commit hook manually using `black . --check` in `.git/hooks/pre-commit` (this just does the check - doesn't fix anything if it fails), but never figured out how to configure black to work with the clean and smudge filters.